# Tengo problemas para retornar todas las opciones de mi bucle for

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, recursión

**Esta es la función que me presentan, la pude resolver pero no encuentro la forma de retornar todas las opciones. solo la primera, intente hacerla con recursión pero no le encuentro la vuelta.**

```
function bienvenidoSr(persona) {
  // La funcion recibe un objeto "persona".
  // de la forma: 
  // {
  //  nombre: 'Lionel
  //  apellido: 'Messi',
  //  invitado: true
  //  }
```

// Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y, además, tiene las propiedades "nombre" y "apellido", tomar esos valores y retorna:
// "Lionel Messi, un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido".
// Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "apellido", retornar:
// "Bienvenido Sr. Messi".
// Si tiene la propiedad "invitado" y solo tiene la propiedad "nombre", retornar:
// "Hola Lionel, tu mesa está lista".
// En caso de que no tenga la propiedad "invitado" retornar:
// "Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta".
//Esta es la función que me presentan, la pude resolver pero no encuentro la forma de retornar todas las opciones. solo la primera, intente hacerla con recursión pero no le encuentro la vuelta.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < persona.length; i++) {
  if(!persona[i].invitado){
    return "Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta";
  }else if(persona[i].invitado && persona[i].nombre && persona[i].apellido){
    return persona[i].nombre + " " + persona[i].apellido + ", un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido"
  } else if(persona[i].invitado && !persona[i].nombre && persona[i].apellido){
 return "Bienvenido Sr. " + persona[i].apellido;
  }else if(persona[i].invitado && persona[i].nombre && !persona[i].apellido){
    return "Hola " + persona[i].nombre + ", tu mesa está lista";
  }
}
}
```

;

```
var personas = [{nombre: 'Toni',apellido: 'Tralice',invitado: true}, {apellido: 'Rodriguez',invitado: true},{nombre: 'Matias',invitado: true},{nombre: 'Leandro',apellido: 'Dominguez'}]
bienvenidoSr(personas)
console.log(bienvenidoSr(personas))
```

Comment: Saludos. Si el resultado es un mensaje por cada `persona`; dentro de la función inicializa un `Array` y en lugar de `return "el mensaje";` pones el nombre de la variable (diganmos se llama `mensajes`) como a continuación `mensajes.push("el mensaje")` esto en cada condición; al final de la función `return mensajes;`.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function bienvenidoSr( persona ) {
      for (let i = 0; i < persona.length; i++) {
      if(!persona[i].invitado) {
          console.log( "Disculpe señor, no está invitado a la fiesta" );
      }
      else if( persona[i].nombre && persona[i].apellido) {
          console.log( persona[i].nombre + " " + persona[i].apellido + ", un gusto tenerlo nuevamente! Bienvenido" );
      } 
      else if( persona[i].apellido ) {
          console.log( "Bienvenido Sr. " + persona[i].apellido );
      }
      else if( persona[i].nombre ) {
          console.log( "Hola " + persona[i].nombre + ", tu mesa está lista" );
      }
    }
}
var personas = [{nombre: 'Toni',apellido: 'Tralice',invitado: true}, {apellido: 'Rodriguez',invitado: true},{nombre: 'Matias',invitado: true},{nombre: 'Leandro',apellido: 'Dominguez'}]
bienvenidoSr(personas)
```

El principal error de tu código, eran los return, que cambié por console.log de forma que impriman el mensaje correspondiente en cada iteración.
Tambien simplifiqué un poco las condiciones, que eran repetitivas, si la persona sobre la que iteramos, no está invitada, se entra en el primer if, por lo que no tiene sentido corroborarlo en los demás, igual pasa con las demás variables.

Nota: se podría modificar los console.log de la función, usando una variable tipo array, que almacenara los distintos mensajes, para al salir del for, devolverla.